# If I place a live video camera on another planet where time moves with a different speed

Tags: general-relativity, time, observers

remember that movie "Interstellar"? Where the astronauts came to a planet where one hour here ment 7 years back on earth?

Well, if you don't:

Imagine a planet, far, far away where time moves in a different speed than back on earth. In "Interstellar" our heroes went to a planet like this one – here, one hour, (I believe) ment 7 years on earth.

And ofc they've spent more time there than intented and when they came back to earth, one of the astronauts daughter has not only outgrown her father, but instead was on old woman now. While he still was more or less his "old" self.

Anyway – I did wonder:

Say the astronaus left a live camera on said planet and then traveled back to earth.

From earth now they saw the live video from the far, far away planet (let's just ignore the time the signal needs to get to earth).

What do the astronauts now see on the live video?

A sped up version of what they experienced on said planet? Something else maybe?

For the camera, time passes at a "normal" speed, but the viewers from earth, were time passes "normally" for them as well, time is said to be way, way slower.

Also, how would this affect the data flow? If somehow the data flow was slowed down on the way, wouldn't it come to sort of an "data jam", where more input is coming through the cable then is actually being views at any given moment? (Or is it the other way round where you only get one frame every, say 10 minutes or so?)

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon called gravitational red shift tells you most of what you want to know.

What happens is that if the camera is on a planet where one hour corresponds to 7 years on Earth, then a viewer on Earth finds that the video stream of the distant events looks really slow. The pictures show the distant people walking around really slowly, and breathing and thinking and doing everything slowly. But since all the other processes near to them are also going slowly (as far as the Earth viewer is concerned), those explorer people don't consider that anything unusual is happening at their location.

A video stream sent in the other direction would tell the explorers that events on Earth are whizzing by.

If light were to travel directly between the two locations, then the light arriving at Earth is very red-shifted, to low frequency, and the light arriving at the other location is very blue-shifted, to high frequency. In fact the ratio of 7 years to 1 hour is so extreme that any visible light sent from Earth would arrive as gamma rays and be in danger of killing the explorers.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to Venus or Mercury and set up a video camera there. Both Venus and Mercury are deeper in the gravitational potential field of the Sun, contributing to time on those planets to "slow down" as compared to Earth.

Both planets also moves faster with respect to the Sun then the Earth does, contributing to time on those planets to slow down as compared to the Earth.

The third effect to account for is surface gravity on the respective planets. Mercury is much lighter then the Earth and Venus so I guess this is an effect contributing to time "moving faster" on Mercury.

If you are livestreaming from Venus, filming a digital clock for instance, people on earth will find the clock moving slow, just a little bit.

If you are sending a signal every ten minutes from Venus, people on Earth receiving that signal will think that the interval is slightly more than ten minutes.

There would also be a "redshift" of the signals. If you are sending using a certain frequency of electromagnetic radiation, people on earth will think you are sending using a slightly lower frequency.

Comment: A good example would be the gps system, where we have live radio feeds from atomic clocks at different depths in a gravitational well.